# Order by match on multiple columns (and with mutiple conditions)

Tags: python, sql, string, postgresql, sql-order-by

My issue is I want to order by match on a specific search string.

This is the logic:

If the  `title, author` or  `isbn` are the same as `search`, show these books first

If the  `title, author` or  `isbn` are the like  `%search`, show these books second

If the  `title, author` or  `isbn` are the like `search%`, show these books third

I'm using *SQLAlchemy*, *Flask* and *PostgreSQL*

This is the code:

```
#keep an unformatted version of search, to be able to order
    unformattedSearch = search
    search = "%" + search + "%"

    result = db.execute("SELECT title, author, isbn FROM books WHERE \
        LOWER(title) LIKE LOWER(:search) OR \
        LOWER(isbn) LIKE LOWER(:search) OR \
        LOWER(author) LIKE LOWER(:search) \
        ORDER BY \
        CASE \
            WHEN title = :search THEN 0 \
            WHEN author = :search THEN 1 \
            WHEN isbn = :search THEN 2 \
            \
            WHEN title LIKE string_agg(:unformattedSearch,'%') THEN 3\
            WHEN author LIKE string_agg(:unformattedSearch,'%') THEN 4 \
            WHEN isbn LIKE string_agg(:unformattedSearch,'%') THEN 5 \
            \
            WHEN title LIKE string_agg('%',:unformattedSearch) THEN 6 \
            WHEN author LIKE string_agg('%',:unformattedSearch) THEN 7 \
            WHEN isbn  LIKE string_agg('%',:unformattedSearch) THEN 8 \
        ELSE 9 \
        END",
        {"search": search, "unformattedSearch": unformattedSearch}).fetchall()
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> column "books.title" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in
>   an aggregate function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing string aggregation (which is what `string_agg()` does) and string concatenation (which is what you want). So Postgres understands your query  as an aggregation one, and bad things happen. You can use `||` to concatenate strings.

Also, you should fix your `where` clause so it really does pattern matching (as of now, it is looking for exact matches on the parameter) - `ilike` comes handy to avoid `lower()` on both operands.

Finally, you can use booleans in the `order by` clause so shorten the query.

```
select title, author, isbn 
from books 
where  
       title  ilike '%' || :search || '%' 
    or isbn   ilike '%' || :search || '%' 
    or author ilike '%' || :search || '%' 
order by 
    (title  = :search) desc,
    (author = :search) desc,
    (isbn   = :search) desc,
    (title  ilike :search || '%') desc,
    (author ilike :search || '%') desc,
    (isbn   ilike :search || '%') desc,
    (title  ilike '%' || :search) desc,
    (author ilike '%' || :search) desc,
    (isbn   ilike '%' || :search) desc
```

Comment: thanks, can't believe I wasted so much time on something that should this simple, I'm new to SQL so I guess this is normal to happen!
Thanks, again!